# Result of "select integer + datetime+char" and "select integer + char+datetime"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

why does:

```
select 1 - '+' - CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/2010',101)
```

...query returns a result, and:

```
select 1 - CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/2010',101) - '+'
```

...gives an error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

> When an operator combines two
>   expressions of different data types,
>   the rules for data type precedence
>   specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the
>   data type with the higher precedence.
>   If the conversion is not a supported
>   implicit conversion, an error is
>   returned. When both operand
>   expressions have the same data type,
>   the result of the operation has that
>   data type.

Note: `Can also subtract a number, in days, from a date` Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189518.aspx

Date time has presedence over varchar and int has presedence over varchar

In your example

```
select (1 - '+') - CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/2010',101)
```

This succeeds due to `1 - '+'` = 1, which can be subtracted from a date.

```
select 1 - CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/2010',101) - '+'
```

This fails becuase 1-anydate = a date, but when you try to subtract a '+' you cannot convert datetime in such a way.